# Is there some problem with changing my Live password?

Tags: password, microsoft-account, xbox-live

I want to change password to my Live account and I use more MS services. I mainly use my Windows Phone 7.5 and XBox 360.

My plan is to change my password on the web and then on my devices.

Is there anything I should know before I do that? Or is this straightforward operation with no catches at all?

Comment: I asked something similar on [Superuser a while back](http://superuser.com/q/501777/302)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward... I did it once because I got an email that my account may be compromised and I was advised to change my pw. You just have to go into the settings of your phone and change the password and everything will work like a charm :)

Comment: I just changed it and tried download app from marketplace. The change-pasword-form poped up automatically. Nice!

Comment: Glad everyting went smoothly! Looks like the guys from MS are capable of making life easier :)